# How to create Emacs key bindings for interactive org-mode functions / org-mode commands with arguments?

Tags: emacs, command, org-mode, key-bindings

with the function `org-deadline`, it is possible to define a due date for tasks in Emacs org-mode. The description looks like this:

```
(org-deadline ARG &optional TIME)

Insert the "DEADLINE:" string with a timestamp to make a deadline.
With one universal prefix argument, remove any deadline from the item.
With two universal prefix arguments, prompt for a warning delay.
With argument TIME, set the deadline at the corresponding date.  TIME
can either be an Org date like "2011-07-24" or a delta like "+2d".
```

I want to create a key binding to set the due date to 1 week in the future directly. So the keybinding should call the `org-deadline` function and give `+1w` as an argument. Writing `(org-deadline nil "+1w")` and then doing an `eval` on that region works as expected.

But why can't I bind that to a key? I tried the following two options:

1. ```
   (defun org-deadline-in-one-week ()
     (interactive)
     (org-deadline nil "+1w"))
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-s") 'org-deadline-in-one-week)
   ```
2. ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-s") (lambda () (interactive) (org-deadline nil "+1w")))
   ```

Both ways fail in the sense that the interactive menu for selecting a date is still shown. It prompts me to select a date with the cursor keys and then confirm with `RET`. But I want to use the interactive function non-interactively and just set the due date to one week in the future. What am I missing?

Update: I am using `Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/)`.

Comment: Which version of org-mode are you using? (Try `M-x org-version`)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that this is a problem with org mode, not with how to handle calling functions which might want to be called interactively in geneal: what you're doing looks right.

Comment: I updated the question with the org mode version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into keymap problems: `C-c C-s` is bound in the `org-mode-map` (to `org-schedule`). That's the major mode keymap for Org mode, and it *overrides* the global map in Org mode buffers. See [Active keymaps in the Emacs Lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html#Active-Keymaps) - in fact, reading (and rereading) the whole chapter is a good idea.

You should do two things: define the key in the `org-mode-map`, not in the global map; and make sure that the key is not defined already (or at least you don't mind losing its current setting). E.g `C-c s` is undefined in the `org-mode-map` (by default), so I would do

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'org-deadline-in-one-week)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and also for referencing the key maps!